# Wait for WebBrowser control to load and run all JavaScript

Tags: javascript, .net, webbrowser-control

```
using (var browser = new WebBrowser()) {
    browser.Navigate(location);

    browser.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(wb_DocumentCompleted);
    while (browser.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete) {
        Application.DoEvents();
    }
    log.Info("READY " + browser.Document.GetElementById("main").InnerText);
}

private void wb_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e) {
    WebBrowser wb = (WebBrowser)sender;
    log.Info("COMPLETED " + wb.Document.GetElementById("main").InnerText);
}
```

Both logs return the element where JavaScript changes have not been applied.

Now I have another WebBrowser in WinForms, and it will load the page at startup. This time I also use the `DocumentCompleted` event, still I get no `javascripted` source.

```
form.webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += (sender, e) => {
    log.Info("READY HIAAR" + form.webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("main").InnerText);
};
```

Lastly, I tried getting the source with a button. First I let the WebBrowser load a page in WinForms, and then I press the button **after 5 seconds**:

```
form.dataButton.Click += (sender, e) => {
    log.Info("READY HIAAR" + form.webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("main").InnerText);
};
```

Only the last `log.info` returns the **actual content that I need**.

How can I catch the event for when all JavaScript has been loaded and run? Clicking defeats the purpose.

Comment: Are you loading JavaScript with the `async` keyword?  That event will pass over it if you are.

Comment: @Middas the page isnt my page, I am not sure, it has like thousands of lines of javascript. but chances are you are correct, is there a solution if that would be the case?

Comment: You may try one of these, I don't know if they will work with `async` though: `SHDocVw.WebBrowser_V1 axBrowser = (SHDocVw.WebBrowser_V1)webBrowser.ActiveXInstance; axBrowser.NavigateComplete += new SHDocVw.DWebBrowserEvents_NavigateCompleteEventHandler(axBrowser_NavigateComplete); axBrowser.DownloadComplete +=new SHDocVw.DWebBrowserEvents_DownloadCompleteEventHandler(axBrowser_DownloadComplete);`

Comment: have you tried to create your browser object on another thread?